# Why does z-index not work with sticky elements?

Tags: javascript, css

I have some rollover effects in a sticky footer and a responsive menu / nav that sticks to the top. When the nav is opened and is long enough to go over the footer it covers everything except the rollovers.

[nav closed http://www.musictheorytutorials.com/navclosed.png](http://www.musictheorytutorials.com/navclosed.png)

[nav open http://www.musictheorytutorials.com/navopen.png](http://www.musictheorytutorials.com/navopen.png)

I have tried lots of changes, searched on here and then tried to rebuild a simple version in jsfiddle as an example of it not working and it worked! However making these changes to my actual page do not...

Here is the jsfiddle that does work: /m_d_a/y7Lj3rms/26/

Here is rge jsfiddle that doesn't: /m_d_a/4bLyt681/5/

I can't get the code tags to work properly when cutting and pasting in either, sorry.

I know there is a lot of javascript, most of which is cut and pasted from linked js plug-in files which I don't understand, so I think it's gonna be something in there. If anyone can trudge through this I would really appreciate it. I will also change the title of this question to reflect a working answer to help people in the future.

Thank you.

Comment: Huh? What is /m_d_a/y7Lj3rms/26/? It's some new way to bypass the "links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code" policy? Since Stack Overflow does not allow you to post the link, you encrypt it in some obscure way, that's it? Did you think you could, eh, respect the policy and just include the code in the question itself?

Comment: @Oriol I stated that I couldn't post the code. "I can't get the code tags to work properly when cutting and pasting in either, sorry." No matter what I did, the 4 space indent etc, code tags, it wouldn't accept it. If there was / is a way to amend this I would have / will. Is it because some of the text is longer than a line? or because each line is not exactly four characters indented? If I can work this out I will happily amend the question... I don't understand what this means: "Did you think you could, eh, respect the policy and just include the code in the question itself? "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just modify this selector in your css

from

```
.menu {
  position: relative;
  z-indez: 100;
}
```

to

```
.menu {
  z-index: 100 !important;
}
```

Comment: Might help if I could spell z-index properly too! Damn... Thank you.